# Swing JComboBox not reloading while switching the Jtabbedpane

Tags: swing

I am trying to re initialize the JComboBox while tab switches from data updating page to page containing JComboBox
my function is like this and it is called as well but doesn't work....

```
private void jTabbedPane2StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
    System.out.println("State change called");
    String[] categories=controller.getCategories();
    ComboBoxModel cmbModel1=new DefaultComboBoxModel(categories);
    jComboBox1.setModel(cmbModel1);
    jComboBox1.validate();
}
```

Comment: post a complete test case see http://sscce.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that controller.getCategories() always returns the same results.

Try to rather use the **focusGained** event for the tab where your combo resides. The **stateChanged** event occurs with every tab click you make.

kingo is right with his comment, since can only guess when the code is incomplete.